# Change map through a drop down

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I'm looking to create a webmap through ESRI's ArcGIS API that changes the currently displayed map through a drop down menu that will switch which web ID is being used.

This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/esri/css/esri.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css">


    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/"></script>
    <script>
      require([
        "dojo/parser",
        "dojo/ready",
        "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
        "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
        "dojo/dom",
        "esri/map", 
        "esri/urlUtils",
        "esri/arcgis/utils",
        "esri/dijit/Legend",
        "esri/dijit/Scalebar",
        "esri/dijit/OverviewMap",
        "dojo/domReady!"
      ], function(
        parser,
        ready,
        BorderContainer,
        ContentPane,
        dom,
        Map,
        urlUtils,
        arcgisUtils,
        Legend,
        Scalebar,
        OverviewMap,
        domConstruct
      ) {
        ready(function(){

        parser.parse();


        arcgisUtils.createMap("c63cdcbbba034b62a2f3becac021b0a8","map").then(function(response){
          //update the app 
          dom.byId("title").innerHTML = response.itemInfo.item.title;
          dom.byId("subtitle").innerHTML = response.itemInfo.item.snippet;

          var map = response.map;



          //add the scalebar 
          var scalebar = new Scalebar({
            map: map,
            scalebarUnit: "english"
          });

          var overviewMapDijit = new OverviewMap({
                     map: map,
                     visible: true
          });
          overviewMapDijit.startup();

          //add the legend. Note that we use the utility method getLegendLayers to get 
          //the layers to display in the legend from the createMap response.
          var legendLayers = arcgisUtils.getLegendLayers(response); 
          var legendDijit = new Legend({
            map: map,
            layerInfos: legendLayers
          },"legend");
          legendDijit.startup();


        });


        });

      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body class="claro">
    <div id="mainWindow" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'headline'" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
      <div id="header" class="shadow roundedCorners" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'top'">
        <div id="title"></div>
        <div id="subtitle"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="map" class="roundedCorners shadow" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'"></div>
      <div id="rightPane" class="roundedCorners shadow" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'left'" >
                <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer">
                    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" id="legendPane"
                        data-dojo-props="title:'Legend', selected:true">
                    <div id="legend"></div>
                </div>
                <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
                    data-dojo-props="title:'Map Selection'">
                    <div id="lppanel" class="roundedCorners">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding:5px;">
                                    <div style="font-size: 16pt; font-weight:bold;">
                                        Choose a Map to Display:
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="padding:10px;">
                                        <select id="lplist">
                                            <option value="choose" selected="selected">(Select an option)</option>
                                            <option value="ypop">Chicago Youth Population</option>
                                            <option value="mhi">USA Median Household Income</option>
                                            <option value="hhs">USA HHS Healthcare Resources</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div id="legend"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm guessing it's something similar to this, but I can't get it to work:

```
function getWebID(value){
          var mapWebID;
            switch (value){
                    case "ypop":
                      mapWebID= "c63cdcbbba034b62a2f3becac021b0a8";
                        break;
                  case "mhi":
                    mapWebID= "1e79439598494713b553f990a4040886";
                    break;
                }
            return mapWebID;
        }
```

Comment: I can't even get this to display, probably because I don't have your css/layout.css file. Either include that or give us some code that doesn't depend on it.

Comment: Please add some more detail about issue! or give some independent code where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing a few things.  First you will need to connect the select to your function using either the dojo/on module or some other way.  You will also need to update the map's web map id, probably by calling create map again.  You may want to wrap that part of the code up in a function and pass it the web map id as a parameter that way when you need to change it, you can simply call the function with a new parameter.